# Imported video starting in third frame

Tags: after-effects

I'm experiencing a problem with After Effects CC 18 where every mp4 video that I import starts in the third frame of the video and not in the first frame. The video and composition and video framerate are the same, but even then the problem continues. Any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: if you go into your composition-settings, what is the start-frame given?

Comment: Starts in zero..

Comment: hmm that's strange... if you take a look at the metadata from the video, does is perhaps start at frame -2?